# What does these docker-containes mean?

Tags: docker

Fisrt, `docker run -d busybox sleep 2000`
Seconde, `ps aux | grep {container id}` to find the `pid`;
Third, `pstree -paAl {pid}` shows the nine strange `docker-containe`;
What does these containes mean? **5214-5222**

Fedora 29, docker.

I don't know how to format the output, but you can try it on your pc.I 
only know the 5213 docker-containe is my container...

```
[emacsliu@localhost ~]$ pstree -aAlp 5213
    docker-containe,5213 
    a82c3cf17ed83570758a80ff84fc9f6ff9e649b3407f4f0bc371f2e3aa5f351e /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/a82c3cf17ed83570758a80ff84fc9f6ff9e649b340
   7f4f0bc371f2e3aa5f351e /usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current
      |-sleep,5232 2000
      |-{docker-containe},5214
      |-{docker-containe},5215
      |-{docker-containe},5216
      |-{docker-containe},5217
      |-{docker-containe},5218
      |-{docker-containe},5219
      |-{docker-containe},5220
      |-{docker-containe},5221
       -{docker-containe},5222
```

Answer (score 2):

`docker-containe` is actually abbreviated `docker-containerd-shim` (or `containerd-shim` on some systems) and it is Docker component. Use other tools, which will show a full process name. For example htop tree view:
[image: htop output]

Ref:

- http://alexander.holbreich.org/docker-components-explained/
- [dockerd vs docker-containerd vs docker-runc vs docker-containerd-ctr vs docker-containerd-shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649592/dockerd-vs-docker-containerd-vs-docker-runc-vs-docker-containerd-ctr-vs-docker-c)